# Cast object at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to perform the following line of code using reflection.

```
IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut desktopShortCut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)WshShell.CreateShortcut(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop.ToString()+"\\Max Y+Y.lnk");
```

I have successfully get the right part of expression.

```
WshShell.CreateShortcut(....)
```

By using

```
this.assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll");

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());

            this.WshShellClass = assembly.GetType("IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShellClass");
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(this.WshShellClass, null);



            object[] parameters = new object[1];
            parameters[0] = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Max Y+Y.lnk";
            MethodInfo methodInfo = this.WshShellClass.GetMethod("CreateShortcut");

            object result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parameters);
```

Now I want to cast it to object of Type `IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut` result in above case and assign it to.

```
IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut desktopShortCut,
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What on earth is the point of doing this late bound?  Just add a reference to c:\windows\system32\wshom.ocx

Comment: I am working on installer project install shield 2011(Limited edition).And run this code as exe in custom action.For some reason i am unable to add refrence.

Answer (score 0):

If `WshShellClass.CreateShortcut` returns a `IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut` then you could just say

```
IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut desktopShortCut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut) result
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: But i am dynamically loading assembly containing Type  IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut .

Comment: If the type is not known at compile time then you cannot cast to it :) Any methods you want to subsequently invoke one the shortcut will have to be through reflection. But you should investigate why you are not able to add reference -- "for some reason" does not seem like a good reason.